# How to fix seg fault on first call to function LPS

Tags: c++, recursion, segmentation-fault

I'm am trying to find the longest palindromic sub-sequence of string `s` where `t` is the number of test cases. I am using recursion to find the palindromic sub-sequence  and, on running gdb, I am getting this output:

```
Thread 3 hit Breakpoint 1, main () at lps.cpp:30
30      cin >> t;
(gdb) n
1
31      while(t--)
(gdb) 
33          string s;
(gdb) 
34          cin >> s;
(gdb) 
abcbd
35          int n = s.length();
(gdb) n
36          int lps = LPS(s, 0, n - 1);
(gdb) 

Thread 3 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000010000096b in LPS (s=..., 
    start=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffeef3fff28>, 
    end=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffeef3fff24>) at lps.cpp:7
7   {
(gdb)
```

d∂∂This is my program and I  used recursion to find the lps.

My logic: If the start and end characters are the same then decrease end and increase start and recurse for the remaining part of the string

If they don't match then include start and exclude end for one call and the exclude start and include end in another call and check both for the longest and return the max for

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int LPS(string s, int start, int end) // start end both inclusive
{
    int n = s.length();
    if(n == 1) // single character left
        return 1;
    if(n == 0) // edge condition for 0 characters
        return 0;

    if(s[start] == s[end])
    {
        return 2 + LPS(s, start + 1, end - 1);
    }
    else
    {
        return max(LPS(s, start + 1, end), LPS(s, start, end - 1));
    }

}


int main() 
{

    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--)
    {
        string s;
        cin >> s;
        int n = s.length();
        int lps = LPS(s, 0, n - 1);
        cout << lps << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would help if you provided a [mcve] which actually builds.

Comment: And when you catch the crash in the debugger, check the backtrace. Is it overly long? Then your recursion is likely too deep, or you have the wrong exit condition (which I guess is the reason, for any string of two or more characters, when will its length ever be `0` or `1`?).

Comment: With the commented line `//int n = s.length();` it doesn't even compile. Please provide code were we don't have to fix typos to reproduce anything. Also it greatly helps, it you don't rely on input, but hardcode a set of data that causes the error. Or at least tell us what input you used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First off, your code doesn't compile, so un-comment initialization of `n`.

   ```
    cin >> s;
    int n = s.length();
    int lps = LPS(s, 0, n - 1);
   ```
2. Your recursion doesn't have correct exit condition. Please note that you're not changing string `s` so it's length aka `n` will be same every time, your exit condition should actually, depend on `begin` and `end` - which are changing, on each call

   ```
    if(begin == end) // single character left
       return 1;
    if(begin > end) // edge condition for 0 characters
       return 0;
   ```

Comment: What do you mean with the first one? If `n` is not declared (as it is, since the line is commented in the original code) it doesn't even compile. When uncommented `n` is assigned a value on both occurences.

Comment: Rather than try to answer, simply vote and comment on why the question doesn't meet the guidelines, THEN answer once it's been amended.

Comment: even when n is uncommented it doesn't work... idk why I commented n my mistake ..